# Constants in Coffeescript and nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, coffeescript

How should I keep constants? For example, I saw a lot of code in Github, where table names, rows, etc, are just hard coded in coffeescript class's method. how to proceed in such kind of constants, how to keep them? And how to keep constants, enums which are shared among modules. I guess I should create separate class only for exposing constants, right? And finally, What's what's the approach of keeping constants and enums among services in case of distributed app. For example, project can consist of several applications, which communicate to each other with sockets. Should I create another app, which only exposes constants? if so, what's the performance impact of this solution?

Comment: Please edit your question to contain one and only one specific question. Remove the "best practice" ones as they usually get closed as opinion based.

Comment: ok, I have split the question into several questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put application wide constants in their own module and export them as uppercase property names on `module.exports`.

```
#constants.coffee
module.exports =
  MAX_CONNECTIONS: 32
  SEASONS: ['WINTER', 'SPRING', 'SUMMER', 'FALL']
  ANSWER: 42
```

No need for a class when you won't be creating many instances of it. You can also set them as module-level variables or class static members (`@MAX_CONNECTIONS = 32`) sign in a coffeescript class definition) as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, I used to use

## constants.coffee

module.value 'SOME_CONSTANT', 'someConstantValue'

for the constants that are needed only on occasion. I think difference between the solution above is that this solution need to be dependency-injected in order to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but I just used this:

```
module.exports.SomeConstant =
    VALUE1: 1
    VALUE2: 2
    VALUE3: 3
```